# How to view another AlertView after dismiss?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

can i display another UIAlertview after dismissed by timer? i use this method UIActivityindicatorview into UIAlertView with NSTimer to dismiss it self "please wait, Saving..." dismissed, then i want to view another UIAlertView say "Saved Successfully!" (Done). how to achieve this? thank you.

here i was use same this method but this not what i'm need. i just need view another UIAlertview after the first uialertview dismissed by timer.

please tell me if need more clear i can post my code here thanks.

```
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView* alert_view = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle: @"Save" message:@"please wait, saving..." delegate: self 
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert_view show];
    [alert_view release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
    if (buttonIndex==0) {

        UIAlertView* alert_view = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle: @"Success" message:@"Saved Successfully!" delegate: self 
                               cancelButtonTitle: @"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];

         [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:TRUE];
    }
    else{
        [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:TRUE];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A timer is not the way to go about this.  You are faking it instead of implementing it properly.  You need to use protocols and delegates if you have multiple classes involved, but ultimately, you need to follow this flow:

1)  Show a "Please wait...Saving" alert

2)  Do the saving

3)  When saving has completed, dismiss first alert, and show second.

Depending on HOW your are saving WHAT, this may need some extra logic to implement, but without more specifics, it's hard to help much more.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice about that. so how to add activity indicator for copying file?